# JavaScript: Multiple dice rollers each with their own summ of dice rolled

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dice

I have a university assignment where I am supposed to code a dice roller.

You can add and subtract dice from the roller. When you press the button to add a dice a d6 is created with a random number of dots ( 1 through 6). You can add up to 40 dice to the roller.

The dice roller shows the sum of the the dice rolled. My problem is that when I open multiple rollers instead of the counter being at zero, the sum of the dice in the first roller is copied. When I add more dice to the new roller, they are added to the sum of the first roller instead of the new roller. In other words:

Dice roller 1 shows the sum of dice roller 1,2,3,4...

Dice roller 2 only shows the initial sum of dice roller 1, and then doesn't update.

How can I stop this from happening? I want each roller to only show the sum of its own dice. In other words:

In dice roller 1, I only want to show the sum of the dice in roller 1.

In dice roller 2, I only want to show the sum of the dice in roller 2.

Here is the code for a die with one dot.

```
// dice-side-one li
var diceSideOne = document.createElement("li");
diceSideOne.className = "dice dice-side-one";
diceSideOne.setAttribute('data-diceValue', '1');
```

Here is the code to calculate the sum of the dice.

```
function getSumDiceValue(){
    var dice = document.getElementsByClassName("dice");                 
    var diceTotal = 0;                                                  
    for(var i = 0; i < dice.length; i++){                               
        diceTotal += Number(dice[i].getAttribute("data-diceValue"));    
    };                            
    return diceTotal;
};
```

Here is the code to show the sum of the dice.

```
// Dice summ li
var totalDiceSumm = document.createElement("p");
totalDiceSumm.className = "dice-summ";
totalDiceSumm.innerHTML = getSumDiceValue();

diceToolbarCounterWrapper.appendChild(totalDiceSumm);
```

(i've just realised sum is only spelled with one 'm')

Comment: I'm reading your question, and I think there just isn't enough information to answer it. You don't provide any html, I do'nt think you've provided the full javascript. IMO your best bet to get an answer is to make a working jsfiddle

Comment: Here is a fiddle with the problem https://jsfiddle.net/txdq7upw/1/

Comment: its this line `document.getElementsByClassName('dice-summ')[0].innerHTML = getSumDiceValue()` that is the issue. You are getting all the elements with `dice-summ` classname but then specifically picking the first element and only updating that

Comment: How do I go about fixing so that each roller just counts it's own dice? I'm pretty new to JavaScript...

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your fiddle. You need to find out which `Add Dice` button is being clicked. Then you can find out which summ to update as its the next element. You can do this with this line:

```
this.nextSibling.innerHTML = getSumDiceValue();
```

`this` references the element being clicked, so `this.nextsibling` references the correct item to update.

```
function insertDice() {
    var diceSideTwo = document.createElement("div");
    diceSideTwo.className = "dice dice-side-two";
    diceSideTwo.innerHTML = "2";
    diceSideTwo.setAttribute('data-diceValue', '2');
    diceWindowWrapper.appendChild(diceSideTwo);
    this.nextSibling.innerHTML = getSumDiceValue(); //use this instead of line below
    //document.getElementsByClassName('dice-summ')[1].innerHTML = getSumDiceValue()
};
```

You still have the issue with looping through all the dice when updating the sum total though.

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scqaqbsw/1/)

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply. I made a fiddle showing the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/txdq7upw/1/

Comment: It's updating in the correct roller now, but unfortunately it is still counting the total of all the dice, like you said. Do you think that the solution is to give every roller a unique ID in some way? If so, how would you go about doing it?

Comment: Yeah you need some way to differentiate between the dice, whether thats an id or tracking which dice is being clicked... thats up to you.